# Why is there a E in the name EM algorithm?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, expectation-maximization, latent-variable, kullback-leibler

I understand where the E step happens in the algorithm (as explicated in the math section below). In my mind, the key ingenuity of the algorithm is the use of the Jensen's inequality to create a lower bound to the log likelihood. In that sense, taking the `Expectation` is simply done to reformulate the log likelihood to fit into Jensen's inequality (i.e. $E(f(x)) < f(E(x))$ for concave function.)

Is there a reason why the E-step is so-called? Is there any significance to the thing that we're taking expectation of (i.e. $p(x_i, z_i| \theta)$? I feel like I'm missing some intuition behind why the Expectation is so central, rather than simply being incidental to the use of Jensen's inequality.

EDIT: A [tutorial](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v26/n8/full/nbt1406.html) says:

> The name 'E-step' comes from the fact that one does not usually need
>   to form the probability distribution over completions explicitly, but
>   rather need only compute 'expected' sufficient statistics over these
>   completions.

What does it mean "one does not usually need to form the probability distribution over completions explicitly"? What would that probability distribution look like?

---

Appendix: E-step in the EM algorithm
$$\begin{align}
ll &= \sum_i{\log p(x_i; \theta)} && \text{definition of log likelihood} \\
&= \sum_i \log \sum_{z_i}{p(x_i, z_i; \theta)} && \text{augment with latent variables $z$} \\
&= \sum_i \log \sum_{z_i} Q_i(z_i) \frac{p(x_i, z_i; \theta)}{Q_i(z_i)} && \text{$Q_i$ is a distribution for $z_i$} \\
&= \sum_i \log E_{z_i}[\frac{p(x_i, z_i; \theta)}{Q_i(z_i)}] && \text{taking expectations - hence the E in EM} \\
&\geq \sum E_{z_i}[\log \frac{p(x_i, z_i; \theta)}{Q_i(z_i)}] && \text{Using Jensen's rule for $\log$ which is concave} \\
&\geq \sum_i \sum_{z_i} Q_i(z_i) \log \frac{p(x_i, z_i; \theta)}{Q_i(z_i)} && \text{Q function to maximize}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking, but I've always assumed that the relevance behind naming the E-step is that, in some sense, you are "filling in" or "imputing" the missing $z$ by taking the expectation. Granted, this isn't exactly what is going on because you are taking $E_\theta [\log p(x, Z; \theta') \mid X = x]$ which isn't the same thing as plugging in something for the missing $Z$ values, but operationally one often ends up doing something like that. If we were doing data augmentation - which is similar to EM in many respects.

Comment: Yes this is the kind of discussion I want to have. So when you say impute z by taking expectation". The expectation of what? Also, do you mean $E_z$ instead of $E_\theta$?

Comment: My upbringing had always been to index the $E$ with the parameter indexing the probability measure that the expectation is being taken with respect to. In CS they do it as you are suggesting. I'm integrating out $Z$, conditioning on $X$ against a measure indexed by $\theta$.

Comment: As an example, when fitting Gaussian mixtures, the E-step imputed the missing class indicators. But it does so in a fuzzy way by calculating responsibilities for each observation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expectations are central to the EM algorithm. To start with, the likelihood associated with the data $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is represented as an expectation
\begin{align*}
p(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta) &= \int_\mathfrak{{Z}^n} p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n;\theta)\,\text{d}\mathbf{\mathfrak{z}}\\
&=\int_\mathfrak{{Z}^n} p(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n,\theta)p(\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n;\theta)\,\text{d}\mathbf{\mathfrak{z}}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ p(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n,\theta)\right]
\end{align*}
where the *expectation* is in terms of the marginal distribution of the latent vector $(\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n)$, which depends on $\theta$.

The intuition behind EM is also based on an expectation. Since $\log p(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta)$ cannot be directly optimised, while $\log p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n;\theta)$ can but depends on the unobserved $\mathfrak{z}_i$'s, the idea is to maximise instead the expected complete log-likelihood $$\mathbb{E}_\vartheta\left[ \log p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n;\theta) \big| x_1,\ldots,x_n \right]$$ *except that this expectation also depends* on a value of $\vartheta$, chosen as $\theta_0$, say, hence the function to maximise (in $\theta$) in the M step:
$$Q(\theta_0,\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}\left[ \log p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n;\theta) \big| x_1,\ldots,x_n \right]$$
Jensen's inequality only comes as a justification for the increase in the *observed* likelihood at each M step.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Since our posterior distribution for the latent vectors changes at every step, does $E_\theta[p(x_1,\dots,x_n, \mathfrak{z}, \dots, \mathfrak{z}, \theta)]$ change at every step as well? If so, [this picture](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-cea38c48bc2002c1ecddabeee5dd4806?convert_to_webp=true) is a bit confusing because there is a fixed red curve representing $p(x;\theta)$, whereas it $p(x;\theta)$ "changes" at every step since we're averaging over our current belief about the latent vectors $z$ at that step.

Comment: sorry I do not understand the question: at each EM step, the value of $\mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ p(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n,\theta)\right]$ changes and increases. This does not mean the likelihood function itself changes.

Comment: Isn't $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta) = \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ p(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n,\theta)\right]$? If the RHS changes according to our posterior belief about the latent vector, does the LHS change as well?

Comment: This identity is in my answer. Both sides take different values when $\theta$ varies. However, in this equation there is no notion of posterior belief as (a) $\theta$ is fixed and (b) the $\mathfrak{z}_i$'s are considered marginally.

Comment: You're right about $\mathfrak{z}_i$ being marginal. To rephrase: I'm taught that at each E-step, we should choose the marginal distribution of $\mathfrak{z}_i$ to be the posterior (i.e. $p(\mathfrak{z}|x, \theta)$) so that $Q(\theta_0, \theta)$ touches $p(x|\theta)$. So at each iteration, we have a new $\theta$, thus a new posterior $p(\mathfrak{z}|x, \theta)$, thus a new marginal distribution for $\mathfrak{z}$, and thus a new $p(x|\theta)$. I'd appreciate you pointing out the flaw in this train of thought?

Comment: At each iteration $t$, the E step uses $p(\mathfrak{z}|x, \theta_t)$ to compute the integral$$Q(\theta_t,\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\theta_t}\left[ \log p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n;\theta) \big| x_1,\ldots,x_n \right].$$ Hence the target function to maximise changes at each iteration $t$. This says nothing about the original target likelihood $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta) = \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ p(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\mathfrak{z}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{z}_n,\theta)\right]$ which only depends on a single $\theta$.

Comment: @Xi'an "Jensen's inequality only comes as a justification for the increase in the observed likelihood at each M step" But this is very important, right, because otherwise there would not necessarily be any point in using the EM-algorithm in the first place. So *both* expectations and Jensen's inequality are central to the EM-algorithm, do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Just some extension regarding the edited part.

> The name 'E-step' comes from the fact that one does not usually need
> to form the probability distribution over completions explicitly, but
> rather need only compute 'expected' sufficient statistics over these
> completions.

Since the value of $z$ is not observed, we estimate a distribution $q_x(z)$ for each data point $x$ as `completions` of the unobserved data. The Q function is the sum of **expected** log likelihoods over $q_x(z)$
$$Q(\theta)=\sum_x E_{q_x}[\log p(x,z|\theta)]$$

The mentioned `probability distribution over completions` should refer to $p(x,z|\theta)$.
For some distributions (especially the exponential family, since the likelihood is in its log form), we only have to know the expected [`sufficient statistics`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/sufficient-statistics-for-layman) (instead of the expected likelihood) in order to compute and maximize $Q(\theta)$.

---

There's a very good introduction in Chapter 19.2 of Probabilistic Graphical Models.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is, why need to introduce $q(z)$? Since the derivation I saw so far that it wants to introduce Jensen's inequality, hence it introduce $q(z)$. But I think without introducing $q(z)$, we  can still have Jensen's inequality by using $p(z)$ directly in the derivation, i.e. $p(x,z;\theta) = p(z) * p(x|z;\theta)$, we can still have the Jensen's inequality, right? Then I'm confused why need to have a separate $q(z)$.