# EM algorithm for multinomial data

Tags: clustering, multinomial-distribution, expectation-maximization

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have a dataset modeled by multinomial data of K cluster.

To apply EM algorithm parameters are :

$${\theta }^{\left(0\right)}=({p}_{k}^{\left(0\right)},k=1,\mathrm{\dots },K)$$

E-Step :

$$\hbox{ Pr }\left({z}_{i,k}=1\mid {X}_{i},{\theta }^{\left(t\right)}\right)=\frac{{P(X_{i}/C_{k}).}{p}_{k}^{\left(t\right)}}{{\sum }_{k=1}^{K}P(X_{i}/C_{k}).{p}_{k}^{\left(t\right)}},\forall $$

Where  : ${z}_{i,k} = 1 $ if $ {X}_{i}\in C_{k} $

M-step :

$${n}_{k}^{(t+1)}={\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{N}}{z}_{i,k}^{(t+1)},\forall k$$

$${p}_{k}^{(t+1)}=\frac{{n}_{k}^{(t+1)}}{N},\forall k.$$

**My question is how to estimate $ P(X_{i}/C_{k}) $ at E-step**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I derive the EM algorithm for a mixture of two Bernoulli distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557302/how-can-i-derive-the-em-algorithm-for-a-mixture-of-two-bernoulli-distributions)

Comment: @mhdadk , I still have confusin in this case

Comment: Specify what is confusing, please. That should form the basis of your question, and edit that question to reflect what you want to know.