# E-Step of the EM algorithm on mixture

Tags: optimization, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution

Im trying to implement the EM algorithm on mixture model: $pg(x) + (1-p)h(x)$ where the sample $\bar{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, is independently generated from the mixture, and $g(x) = e^{-x}$ and $h(x) = x^3 \frac{e^{-x}}{6}$. I want to calculate the E-step for this algorithm.

I already know that:

$$L(p | \bar{x}, \bar{Z}) = \prod_{i=1}^n pe^{-x_i} \mathbb{I}_{Z_i = 1}  + (1 - p)  x_i^3 \frac{e^{-x_i}}{6} \mathbb{I}_{Z_i = 0}$$.

I know that the E-step consists on calculating the expectation of the function $L$, but I don't know how to obtain this expected value. How do calculate the expected value on a mixture model? What should I do with the indicative function?

Any hints or advices are more than welcome.

Comment: Given the magnitude of your questions, I think you should invest into reading a detailed introduction to EM, eg [The EM Algorithm and Extensions by McLachlan & Krishnan.](https://amzn.to/3abeFGR)

Comment: Yes @Xi'an, there's a type in $g(x)$ , im editing the question, thank you for noticing

Comment: @Xi'an I realized i was asking to many questions, deleted the programming part of the question and limited it to the thing im having more difficulty: finding $Q(\theta | \theta^{(t)})$

Comment: I believe this question and its answer would be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/557302/296197