# Concrete example of what Sufficient Statistics is

Tags: intuition, sufficient-statistics

Having read articles to try to understand Sufficient Statistics.

- [Sufficient statistics for layman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/sufficient-statistics-for-layman)

> A sufficient statistic **summarizes all the information contained** in a sample so that you would make the same parameter estimate whether we gave you the sample or just the statistic itself. It's reduction of the data without information loss.

- [Sufficient statistic From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic)

> In statistics, a statistic is sufficient with respect to a statistical model and its associated unknown parameter if "no other statistic that can be calculated from the same sample provides any additional information as to the value of the parameter".

- [An introduction to the concept of a sufficient statistic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j4E2FRR384)
- [Example of Sufficient and Insufficient Statistic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146234/example-of-sufficient-and-insufficient-statistic)

However, it is still not clear to me what it is exactly. Please provide a concrete and real world example on what Sufficient Statistics is.

For instance, suppose $X$ is the entire statistics of stock trade volume by every trader each day and we only care about $\theta$, which is the average trade volume per day per trader. $t$ is the date, $i$ is the trader ID, and $N$ is the number of traders.

For the objective of calculating $\theta$, we only need to retain $$ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} x(t, i)$$

Is this Sufficient statistics $\phi(X)$ for $X$ with regard to $\theta$? Is the objective of Sufficient Statistics to reduce the volume of data by finding smaller set of data to calculate a specific estimate?

[image]

Or is $ \pi / 4$ the Sufficient Statistics with regard to the sum for the infinite number of elements
$$
\int_0^1 1 dx 
+ \int_0^1 \frac {-1}{2} x^2 dx  
+ \int_0^1 \frac {-1}{8} x^4 dx 
+ \int_0^1 \frac {-1}{16} x^6 dx 
+ \int_0^1 \frac {-5}{128} x^8 dx 
\text{  + ...} 
$$

[image]
* image is from [The Discovery That Transformed Pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMlf1ELvRzc)

## Note

> Sufficient statistics are a set of statistics that fully describe the distribution of a sample in a statistical model. They are **a subset of the sample data that contain all of the information needed to make inferences about the population parameters, and they are independent of any specific distributional assumptions made about the data**.
>
> For example, consider a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. The sample mean $\bar{x}$ and sample variance $s^2$ are sufficient statistics for estimating the population mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, respectively. This is because the sample mean and sample variance contain **all of the information needed to make inferences about the population mean and standard deviation**.
>
> Sufficient statistics are useful because they allow us to make statistical inferences about a population without having to specify the exact form of the distribution of the data. They also **allow us to make inferences about the population using a smaller set of data**, which can be more efficient and accurate in some cases.

Comment: Sufficiency or lack thereof depends on the statistical model attached to the data.

Comment: I am sure that among the [500 or so threads asking about sufficient statistics on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sufficient+statistic%22+is%3Aquestion) you can find many concrete examples.

Comment: @whuber, I am afraid there are not even as many as 10 with concrete real world examples. Hope you could point to one. If there are so many, I suppose it means Sufficiency is not well explained anywhere.

Comment: *One* concrete example would suffice, right??

Comment: @whuber, yes. By which we learners trying and trying to understand can get the idea and what it is like in the real world.

Comment: As I pointed out--and you seem to agree--those examples already exist.  Questions asking for lists of stuff are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @whuber, I am not trying to argue, but with all the due respect, I am not asking a list. Even just yes or no to the trader example is Sufficient Statistics can help. If it is not correct, then it is also a step by knowing what Sufficient Statistics is not.